# Typescript How to update every object value

Tags: typescript

I have a object like this:

```
enum FeatureNames = {
  featureA = 'featureA',
  featureB = 'featureB',
  featureC = 'featureC'
}

interface FeatureDetails {
  on: boolean;
}

type Features = Record<FeatureNames,FeatureDetails>;

const myObj: Features = {
  [FeatureNames.featureA]: {
    on: true
  },
  [FeatureNames.featureB]: {
    on: false
  },
  [FeatureNames.featureC]: {
    on: false
  }
}
```

How can I update the value of every member of `myObj` so the `on` value is true?

Without typescript I would just use reduce, but I get a overload error when I try to do so.

Here's the error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Record'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Record'.ts(7053)

Comment: Consider editing your code to constitute a [mcve] as described by [ask].  What's `FeatureNames`?  What's `FeatureDetails`? What specific error do you see and in what code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicit cast the `key` argument within the reduce function:

```ts
Object.keys(myObj).reduce((obj, key) => (obj[key as FeatureNames].on = true, obj), myObj)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I needed to do.  It is super tedious to do though...